# Showing custom block/message on shipping method section in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, error-message

I have some business logic after entering shipping address or select shipping address, for these, I override the `_formRateRequest` and `setRequest` methods from core class `\Magento\Fedex\Model\Carrier` in my custom module, and my business logic is working. After successfully validated I need to show the custom block or custom message in shipping method section after shipping address entered or select.

[image]

But here I confusing how to start and where to start?

Any suggestions? on this.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need override selectAddress function from below file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js
```

And show a html containing your message.You can keep hide on load, and on selecting shipping method you can show this.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will check and let you know.